# Updating Status of Message From unread to read using Ajax - MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying update status of every each Message from unread to read and when i click on button of first message in the list updating status going to work,but when i click on button of second or Third message in the list updating status NOT going to work. Can anyone please help me or point me in the right direction!
Thanks in advance :)

View:

```
 <div class="content">
    @{ int i = 0;}
    foreach (var item in Model.Comment_Lists.GroupBy(l => l.MSG).Select(g => .First()))    {
            if (item.se == "Kunde")
            {
              <div  class="bs-callout bs-callout-success">
              <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
              <button data-toggle="collapse"  data-target="#ShowMSG_@i" id="btnChangestu" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-icon"></button></div>
              <span class="text-muted"><small> @item.Date.ToString("dd/MMMM/yyy")</small></span><br />
              <span class="text-muted"><small> @item.MSGType</small></span>
              <input type="hidden" name="IDMSG" id="IDMSG" value="@item.id" />
              <input type="hidden" name="ChangeStu" id="ChangeStu" value="Read Message" />
              <div class="collapse" id="ShowMSG_@i">
                  <p><span>@item.MSG </span></p>
              </div>
              </div>
              }
                i++;
           }
         </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {    
        $("#btnChangestu").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();    
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Account/UpdateMSGStatus",
                data: {
                    IDMSG: $("#IDMSG").val(),
                    ChangeStu: $("#ChangeStu").val()
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {    
                    if (!$.trim(result)) {
                        alert("What follows is blank: ");
                    }
                    else {                            
                        result.ID = IDMSG;
                        result.MSGType = ChangeStu;    
                        console.log("Send");    
                    }    
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
                }
            })    
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
public JsonResult UpdateMSGStatus(int? IDMSG , string ChangeStu)
{
    var u = db.Besked.Where(a => a.ID == IDMSG).FirstOrDefault();
    if (u != null)
    {
        u.MSGType = ChangeStu;
        u.ID = IDMSG;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return Json(u, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html, and your jQuery selectors will only ever select the first item with the `id`. Use class names and relative selectors

Comment: Or better, just delete the hidden inputs and assign the values to `data-*` attributes of the button, and read them using `$(this).data(...)`

Comment: Hi @StephenMuecke :) would you please give me ex with your second comments :) Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html, and your jQuery selectors (`IDMSG: $("#IDMSG").val()` etc) will only ever select the first element with that `id`.

There is no reason to use hidden inputs in this case. Instead, ad the values as `data` attributes and read then in the `.click()` event, and use a `class` name for the button instead of an `id`.

Note I have only included the `IDMSG`, not `ChangeStu` since you have hard coded that value

```
<button data-id="@item.id" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-icon edit" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ShowMSG_@i></button>
```

Then the script becomes

```
$('.edit.).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    // read the value
    var id = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateMSGStatus", "Account"), // don't hard code urls
            data: {
                IDMSG: id,
                ChangeStu: 'Read Message' 
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
```

Comment: thanks Stephen , its working fine :) i just allowed myself to ask one more question , i hope its ok :) now status will be changed , but i sholud refresh page to see changes , is there anything i can do to see changes without refreshing page ?!

Comment: There is no point refreshing the page if you are making an ajax call - you should be just updating the DOM in the success callback. What is it that you want to update? (I assume one thing would be that once you click the button, you would not want to call the db and save it again if you click it again?)

Comment: Yes I'am using ajax , but i couldnt see the changes unless i refresh page. i want update status of  Message (when user come to the page status is unread MSG, and when they hit button its going to update status from unread to read) and  also you right its going save to db again when user hit button to expand msg.

Comment: But which element do you want to update? (sorry, but I cannot guess what you code currently displays)

Comment: i just updated my question with Screenshots :) and this element contains status and i also want to update (which we doing now ,but the only problem is i should refresh page :  <span class="text-muted"><small > @item.MSGType</small></span>

Comment: If that is all you want to update, then your controller method only needs to return a `true` or `false` value (indicating the database was updated - e.g `return Json(true);`. The you give the `<span>` a `class` name and use a relative selector to update the text, and remove the handler so future clicks are ignored. Give me 30 min or so and I will update the answer

Comment: thanks for great explanation and useful answer Stephen :)